# CMD in dockerfile vs command in docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

What is the difference?

Which is preferred?

Should CMD be omitted if command is defined?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In the common case, you should have a Dockerfile `CMD` and not a Compose `command:`.

`command:` in the Compose file overrides `CMD` in the Dockerfile.  There are some minor syntactic differences (notably, Compose will never automatically insert a `sh -c` shell wrapper for you) but they control the same thing in the container metadata.

However, remember that there are other ways to run a container besides Compose.  `docker run` won't read your `docker-compose.yml` file and so won't see that `command:` line; it's also not read in tools like Kubernetes.  If you build the `CMD` into the image, it will be honored in all of these places.

The place where you do need a `command:` override is if you need to launch a non-default main process for a container.

Imagine you're building a Python application.  You might have a main Django application and a Celery worker, but these have basically the same source code.  So for this setup you might make the image's `CMD` launch the Django server, and override `command:` to run a Celery worker off the same image.

```sh
# Dockerfile
# ENTRYPOINT is not required
CMD ["./manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8080"]
```

```yaml
# docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports: ['8080:8080']
    # no command:
  worker:
    build: .
    command: celery worker
```

Comment: do you mind expanding a bit on `ENTRYPOINT` not being required, and why specifying `CMD` instead?

Comment: The entrypoint and command are just concatenated to form a single command.  `ENTRYPOINT` defaults to an empty list.  I prefer setting `CMD` for two reasons: `docker run image alternate command` is a little easier to write than `docker run --entrypoint alternate image command`; and there's a common pattern of using the entrypoint for doing startup-time setup, then ending with `exec "$@"` to run the command.  If you don't need the wrapper, and you don't mind the syntactic differences, then in principle it doesn't really matter which you use.

Answer (score 10):

`command` overrides the `CMD` in `dockerfile`.
If you control the `dockerfile` yourself, put it there. It is the cleanest way.

If you want to test something or need to alter the `CMD` while developing it is faster than always changing the `dockerfile` and rebuild the image.

Or if it is a prebuilt image and you don't want to build a derivate `FROM ...` image just to change the `CMD` it is also a quick solution doing it by `command`.